# DYnamically add a javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a situation in my code where i check if my webpage is being viewed by a mobile browser or a desktop browser and based on that i want to load the javascript files that contain the events. I have the following code

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
){
   addJavascript('js/mobileEvents.js','body');

}                                
else{
     addJavascript('js/mouseEvents.js','body');
}
```

My addJavascript function is as follows

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos)
{
  var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName(pos).item(0);
  var oScript= document.createElement("script");
  oScript.type = "text/javascript";
  oScript.src=jsname;
  oHead.appendChild(oScript);
}
```

But the scripts doesnt load. Please help me.

Comment: Wichi document event you are using to do this?

Comment: Check if the generated HTML is `<script ...></script>` and not `<script ... />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JS:

```
function addJavascript(url){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  var scriptNode = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  scriptNode.parentElement.insertBefore(script, scriptNode);
}
```

If you have jQuery in the page just use:

```
$.getScript(url);
```

This is a jsFiddle demo that will load different jQuery-UI lib version based on the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/8fC6w/

Comment: Is it reachable the URL of the script you are trying to load?

Comment: Added a jsFiddle demo. Are you testing with a particular browser?

Comment: Am testing with chrome,firefox and IE. thanks a lot for your efforts but its not working. None of the javascript files are being included.

Comment: hey marc sorry...its working....problem was with my code....had a bug...really very sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Try with [LABjs](http://labjs.com/description.php)

> This project is a simple little tool for being able to load javascript files dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the HTML, you could define `jsname` in the head, and simply add the script tag to the body in the HTML.

`<script>document.write('<script src="'+jsname+'"></script>')</script>`

Comment: i want to dynamically load js files via javascript function